Decadence pre-war partying before enlisting
I'm looking for a movie. It depicts the emptiness of a man's life - he attends parties, drinks. I'm not sure if they are gay, but males wear makeup. In the end of the movie, he washes away mascara and enters an open car with men already sitting there, who go to war (against Nazis).
The movie looks "new", it's probably around early 1990's
